# Add next and previous to simply reviews fader

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple fade in and out list script. Would like to add a left and right arrow to these so users can click previous and next.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divs = $('li[class^="testimonial-"]').hide(),
      i = 0;

  (function cycle() {
    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(800)
      .delay(8000)
      .fadeOut(800, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length;
  })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="testimonials">
  <li class="testimonial-1">“Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."</li>
  
  <li class="testimonial-2">“Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And what have you done so far ? I don't see any attempt to add the prev/next actions.

Comment: You'll need a way to cancel the current auto-slide.  So change the fadeOut callback to call a setTimeout and store the return.   Then your button can just cancel the timeout and call `cycle()`.   If you want backwards, then add a parameter to cycle and change `++i` to `i=i+direction` where direction is the parameter of 1 or - 1